# glibc detected outfile: free(): invalid pointer:

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, free, glibc

My code is giving glibc error.Can someone please point out my mistake.
   This code is used to tokenize words. How do i solve these problems using GDB or any other tool that can be helpful. The code is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct token
{
  char *token;
  int length;   
};

void freeing(gpointer item) 
{
 free(((struct token*)item)->token);
 }


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     int start1 = 0, start2 = 0, i =0;

     struct token *tk = NULL;
     char line[256], *temp = NULL;

     FILE *fp1 = NULL;
     FILE *fp2 = NULL;

     GSList *list = NULL, *iterator = NULL;
     fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w+");

     if (NULL == fp1)
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"cant open %s",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

   if (NULL == fp2)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"cant open %s",argv[2]);
      return 1;
   }    

  while (1)
  { 

   if (NULL == fgets(line, 255, fp1))
     break;

   tk = (struct token *)malloc(sizeof(struct token));

   start1 = -1; start2 = -1;

  for(temp = line,i = 0; temp[i] != '\n'; i++)
  {
      if ((temp[i] == ',')  || (temp[i] == ' ') || (temp[i] == ';') || (temp[i] == '.'))
         start2 = i;

      if (start1 == start2)
        continue;



    tk->token = strndup(line + (start1+1), start2 - (start1+1));
    tk->length = strlen(tk->token);
    list = g_slist_append(list, tk);

    start1 = start2;    

  }

    tk->token = strndup(line + (start1+1), strlen(line));
    tk->length = strlen(tk->token);
    printf("\ntk->length : %d\n",tk->length);
    list = g_slist_append(list, tk );


 }


  for (iterator = list;  iterator; iterator = iterator->next)
  {
    printf("%s -> ",((struct token *)(iterator->data))->token);
    printf("%d\n",((struct token*)iterator->data)->length);
  }

  g_slist_foreach(list, (GFunc)freeing, NULL);

 fclose(fp1);
 fclose(fp2);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please format your code, remove unnecessary casts and indent it consistently.

Comment: `list = g_slist_append(list, tk);` is being called repeatedly in the `for` loop with the same `tk` value. That is, you are queuing the same element multiple times. Hence freeing the same token multiple times. So the first free will succeed and any subsequent free will result in the error you have shown. Note that there are other errors in your code like memory leaks and memory corruptions. A good debugging tool for memory issues is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: i am allocating  new space for every new token that has been read and storing it in list. Isn't this right??

Comment: The allocation is for `tk->token` but they are all belong to the same `tk`. That is, every time you do a new allocation you overwrite the old `tk->token` value. That leads to a memory leak as well as the double free error you are seeing. If you can't see that then add a `printf("%p\n", item)` at the beginning of the `freeing` function. You will find the same value repeated.

Comment: can you please explain how to change my code.

Comment: No I can't. 1. The code is barely readable due to the inconsistent indenting already pointed out. 2. You have not explained in detail what the code is supposed to do. You have said it is to "tokenize words" but that is hardly a full description.

Comment: what is the command line you are using to compile and link the posted code?

Comment: for readabillity, please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement

Comment: in general, never access argv[] beyond `argv[0]` until after checking `argc` to assure the parameters were actually entered on the command line.  Then, if argc does not contain the right value then output a 'usage' message and exit.  Normally, do this check before making any other code commitments

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, immediately check the returned value and if NULL, then call `perror();` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  to output the system message and the enclosed text to stderr, followed by the system error message as to why the system thinks it could not open the file

Comment: Thank you for advice @user3629249

Answer (score 1):

the following code has the major problems fixed, but not the logic errors in the loop :

```
for(int i=0, temp = line; temp[i] != '\n'; i++)
{
    ...
}

tk->token = strndup(line + (start1+1), strlen(line));
tk->length = strlen(tk->token);
printf("\ntk->length : %d\n",tk->length);
list = g_slist_append(list, tk );
```

the suggested fixes for the majority of the problems in the posted code are corrected in the following:

added final call to `g_slist_free(list);` so all the instances of the `struct token` are returned to the heap.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN (256)

struct token
{
    char *token;
    int length;
};

void freeing(gpointer item)
{
    free(((struct token*)item)->token);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( 3 != argc )
    { // then incorrect number of command line arguments
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <inputfile> <outputfile>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line arguments

    FILE *fp1 = NULL;
    FILE *fp2 = NULL;

    if( NULL == (fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen for %s for read failed\n", argv[1]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( NULL == (fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w+") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen for %s for write failed\n", argv[2]);
        fclose( fp1 ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful



    GSList *list = NULL;
    GSList *iterator = NULL;

    char line[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];
    struct token *tk = NULL;
    char *temp = NULL;

    while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp1) )
    {

        if( NULL == (tk = malloc(sizeof(struct token)) ) )
        { // then malloc failed
            perror( "malloc for struct token failed");
            fclose( fp1 );
            fclose( fp2 );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        size_t start1 = 0;
        size_t start2 = 0;

        temp = line;
        for(size_t i=0; temp[i] != '\n'; i++)
        {
            if ((temp[i] == ',')  || (temp[i] == ' ') || (temp[i] == ';') || (temp[i] == '.'))
                start2 = i;

            if (start1 == start2)
                continue;

            tk->token = strndup(line + (start1+1), start2 - (start1+1));
            tk->length = (int)strlen(tk->token);
            list = g_slist_append(list, tk);

            start1 = start2;
        } // end for

        tk->token = strndup(line + (start1+1), strlen(line));
        tk->length = (int)strlen(tk->token);
        printf("\ntk->length : %d\n",tk->length);
        list = g_slist_append(list, tk );

    } // end while


    for (iterator = list;  iterator; iterator = iterator->next)
    {
        printf("%s -> ",((struct token *)(iterator->data))->token);
        printf("%d\n",((struct token*)iterator->data)->length);
    }

    g_slist_foreach(list, (GFunc)freeing, NULL);
    g_slist_free(list);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what, exactly, is the error?   When using the `glibc` facility, the parameters to the compiler become very 'unusual'.  Here is what I'm using when compiling with gcc under the geany editor: gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=c99 -c "%f" -I/usr/include/mpi  `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`  where the "%f" becomes the name of the file being compiled.  Notice there are several back ticks required that will not show well in this comment

Comment: My understanding is you are on ubuntu linux.  have you downloaded/installed the 'glibc' by something like: `sudo apt-get install glibc` ?   I ask because this code compiles without any errors for me.